# What free javascript editor can do this kind of intellisense

Tags: javascript, ide, intellisense, javascript-intellisense

I'm looking for this specific type of intellisense workflow. 
This is what i used for 10 years working with VB6 IDE. 
And this is how i like the intellisense to work...

Say i'm coding a javascript ...

1. if type **document.** the moment i type the dot, the list comes up with all the methods and properties of the document object   (without the need to press anything else)
2. i can then use UP/DOWN Arrow keys, to select a method/properties from the list.
3. as i type more characters, the list is reduced
4. if i type a character that is not allowed as part of a method/property name (for example space), the list disappears, and what i typed stays, but the character i typed (space) is added normally.  I hate it when these intellisense IDE's decide to add () for me, and my cursor is trapped between the ().

Comment: Henchman's answer makes me re-parse your question. Do you want: An IDE written in JavaScript? Or do you want an IDE that has special support for JavaScript conventions?

Comment: @sarnold I interpreted it as a question asking about IDEs that provide content assist/code completion/intellisense/&c. for JS.

Comment: @MДΓΓ, that's two to one. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2):

[JetBrains' WebStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) is pretty nice, though not free. [Komodo Edit](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-edit) is free.

Comment: Be careful of Komodo Edit 7, it has some buggy javascript code completion: http://community.activestate.com/node/8824 .